# MQTT Broker - Mosquitto Message Logging

Tags: logging, mqtt, mosquitto

Is it possible to log MQTT Broker Mosquitto events such as messages published to all channels, subscriptions, client connections/disconnections and errors to a log file with a time stamp and then have program insert this into a database either  SQL in encrypted form?

If so, how could this be achieved?

What I have tried?

I have subscribed to the topic **$SYS/broker/#** ,able to get only connection logs,My query here is how can i get what message is sent and received from broker?

**Reference Link :** http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-logging/

Answer (score 2):

You can add all or a subset of the following entries to the `mosquitto.conf` file to enable various logging levels and add a timestamp:

```
log_dest stdout
log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true
log_timestamp_format [%H:%M:%S]
```

This will redirect all Mosquitto logging to `stdout`, which you can then either pipe into a custom program that ingests it and persists to a database or redirect the output to a file and later process it.

Comment: I'm having log_type as all ,Instead of doing like ,I thought of subscribing to "$SYS topic ,Store all logic in to file,Am i following correct approach?